# Can rsync verify contents before syncing

Tags: linux, file, checksum, rsync

Can Rsync be configured to verify the contents of the file before they are being synced. I have heard about checksum, but I came to know that checksum only does a sampling. I want to transfer a file only if it is contents are changed and not timestamp, is there a way to do it with any of the rsync modes. 
In my scenario, say file sample.text will be created every week and I want to sync it with a remote server only if the contents of sample.text are changed, since it is created every week, the time stamp would obviously change. But I want the transfer only on a content change.

Comment: Have you tried the man page for rsync?
-c, --checksum
This  changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer.  Without this option, rsync uses a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file's size  and  time  of  last  modification  match  between the sender and receiver.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes:

```
$ man rsync | grep "\--checksum"
    -c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

Rsync is pretty complicated. I recommend cuddle time with the man page and experimentation with test data before using it for anything remotely important.

Most of the time, people use `rsync -ac source dest`.

```
$ man rsync | grep "\--archive"
 -a, --archive               archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)
```

And that `-rlptgoD` garbage means: *recursive* (`r`), *copy symlinks as symlinks* (`l`), *preserve permissions* (`p`), *preserve times* (`t`), *preserve group* (`g`), *preserve owner* (`o`), *preserve device files* (`D`, super-user only), *preserve special files* (also part of `D`).

The `-c` or `--checksum` is really what you are looking for (*skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size*). Your supposition that rsync only samples mtime and size is wrong.

Comment: + for _cuddle time with the man page and experimentation with test data_ - Extremely good advice

Answer (score 9):

See the `--checksum` option on the rsync man page.

Also, the `--size-only` option will be a faster choice if you know for sure that a change of contents also means a change of size.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo > diff.txt
rsync -rvcn --delete /source/ /destination/ > diff.txt
second_row=$(sed -n '2p' diff.txt)
if [ "$second_row" = "" ]; then
    echo there was no change
else 
    echo there was change   
fi
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: If there was no change the second row of diff.txt in verbose mode of rsync  is empty, sed examine this second line.